# Get all startdate and enddate as comma seperate in stuff query

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hi I have startdate as GetDate()-5 and enddate as GetDate()

I am passing this date in variable i.e. this dates are not stored in any table so how can I get records as

GetDate()-5,GetDate()-4,GetDate()-3,GetDate()-2,GetDate()-1,GetDate()

in sql server

I have tried below query which is totally wrong, Can any one please suggest me

```
declare @startdate date
declare @enddate date
set @startdate =GETDATE()-5
set @enddate =GETDATE()

  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()-5))
  FROM [Table]--What should be here?
  WHERE CONVERT(date,AETE.TimeEntryDate) between CONVERT(DATE,@startdate)
  AND CONVERT(DATE, @enddate)       
  FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'')
```

Comment: Do you just need to show a comma-separated list of the last 5 days? If so, would simple string concatenation work? Something like `SELECT GETDATE() - 5 + ', ' + GETDATE() - 4 + ... + GETDATE()`?

Comment: The Getdate() will come dynamic some some time it would be as getdate()-4 to getdate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CTE might come in handy here:

```
    declare @startdate date = dateadd(D, -5, getdate())
declare @enddate date = getdate();

with cte(d) as (
    select @startdate
    union all
    select dateadd(D, 1, d)
    from cte
    where d < @enddate
)
select stuff((
select ', ' + convert(nvarchar(255), d, 101)
from cte
for xml path('')), 1, 2, '')
```

gives you:

```
08/09/2018, 08/10/2018, 08/11/2018, 08/12/2018, 08/13/2018, 08/14/2018
```

Note that this gives you 6 days---the 5 days less than today, as well as today's date.

Comment: semma.. It used for lean recursive cte to me

Comment: if I am passing declare startdate = getdate() - 1;
declare enddate = getdate(); I need only 2 dates that is of today and yesterday

Comment: And that is what you'll have: In my query, if you set `@startdate` to `GETDATE() - 1`, you'll have 2 dates separated by commas.